# How to overcome this onclick event failure in JS?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a simple game. There screen is divided on two and on both sides there are smiling faces generated. Left side, however, contains one more smiling face. After clicking on it, you should get to the next level, where there's 5 more smiling faces on each side. The goal is to find the odd smiling face on the left side each time.

I have this problem, though: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null**

It appears that it's related to this line: **theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = function nextLevel(event){**

What's the problem? Here's the rest of my JS part of code.

```
var numberOfFaces = 5;
var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
var theRightSide = document.getElementById("rightSide");
var theBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

function generateFaces(){
    var i = 0;
    while(i < numberOfFaces){
        var top = Math.random() * 400;
        top = Math.floor(top);
        var left = Math.random() * 400;
        left = Math.floor(left);

        var face = document.createElement("img");
        face.setAttribute("src", "http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png");
        face.style.top = top + "px";
        face.style.left = left + "px";

        theLeftSide.appendChild(face);
        i++;
    }
    leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
    leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.lastChild);
    theRightSide.appendChild(leftSideImages);
};

theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = function nextLevel(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    while (theLeftSide.firstChild){
        theLeftSide.removeChild(theLeftSide.firstChild);
    }
    while (theRightSide.firstChild){
        theRightSide.removeChild(theRightSide.firstChild);
    }
    numberOfFaces += 5;
    generateFaces();
};
    theBody.onclick = function gameOver(){
        alert("Game Over!");
        theBody.onclick = null;
        theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = null;
    };
```

I'd be very grateful for your help. Thank you.

Comment: Well that means lastChild is null...

Comment: It looks like generateFaces() is what adds child nodes to "theLeftSide".  So  there is no lastChild available until after it is clicked.  Try adding generateFaces() outside of the click events to first populate the sides with at least one child.

Answer (score 1):

Last child returns null if the DOM element has no children. Check to make sure that the "#leftSide" DOM element has a child.

From [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/lastChild):

> The `Node.lastChild` read-only property returns the last child of the node. If its parent is an element, then the child is generally an element node, a text node, or a comment node. It returns null if there are no child elements.

Comment: Thank you hunterc and you @Kyle! I've put both theLeftSide.lastchild.onclick and theBody.onclick parts into function generateFaces() and it works perfectly now! :) Now I'm aware of another thing, great, thank you! :)